Чтение массива структур из бинарного файла - C++
Я - новичок в С++. Для разработки использую IDE C++Builder 10.4. Мне необходимо:

Считать из StringGrid в массив структур некоторые ячейки (20 строк и 2 столбца), а затем записать этот массив структур в бинарный файл (.bin).
Считать данные из этого бинарного файла обратно в массив структур, а затем записать данные из массива структур в ячейки StringGrid.
Но уже после чтения данных из файла при попытке помещения информации из массива структур в StringGrid получаю ошибку C++Builder:

Abnormal program termination
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такой проблемой?...
Моя структура имеет вид:
`struct reader
{
    String name;
    String phone;
};`

Запись в файл делаю так:
`   String filename = ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + "readers.bin";
    // Массив структур для записи
    reader * readersInfo = new reader[20];

    // Заполнение массива структур значениями из таблицы
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        readersInfo[i].name = ScheduleGrid->Cells[0][i + 1];
        readersInfo[i].phone = ScheduleGrid->Cells[1][i + 1];
    }

    // Открытие файла для записи
    FILE *stream;
    if ((stream = _wfopen(filename.c_str(), L"w")) == nullptr)
    {
        ShowMessage("Не удается открыть файл \"readers.bin\".");
    }
    // Запись массива структур в файл
    if (fwrite(readersInfo, sizeof(readersInfo[0]), 20, stream) != 20)
    {
        ShowMessage("Ошибка записи файла \"readers.bin\".");
    }
    fclose(stream);`

Чтение из файла пытаюсь реализовать таким образом:
`   String filename = ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + "readers.bin";
    FILE *stream;
    // Массив для чтения структур
    reader readersInfo[20];

    // Открытие файла для чтения
    if ((stream = _wfopen(filename.c_str(), L"r")) == nullptr)
    {
        ShowMessage("Не удается открыть файл \"readers.bin\".");
    }

    // Чтение массива структур из файла
    if (fread(readersInfo, sizeof(readersInfo[0]), 20, stream) != 20)
    {
        ShowMessage("Ошибка чтения файла \"readers.bin\".");
    }

    // Заполнение таблицы значениями из массива структур
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        ScheduleGrid->Cells[0][i + 1] = readersInfo[i].name;
        ScheduleGrid->Cells[1][i + 1] = readersInfo[i].phone;
    }

    fclose(stream);`

Однако уже при попытке помещения информации из массива структур в ScheduleGrid на строке:
`ScheduleGrid->Cells[0][i + 1] = readersInfo[i].name;`

получаю ошибку C++Builder:
Abnormal program termination
Как можно избежать этой ошибки? Прошу вашей помощи...

Вы пишете в файл указатели, а не тело строк. При чтении указатели не имеют смысла. В данном случае проще работать с текстовым файлом. Если непременно нужен бинарный - пишите в него длину строки, затем тело строки. Читайте аналогично - прочитали длину, задали длину строки, прочитали тело

Спасибо Вам за совет! А как мне в таком случае писать в текстовый файл - если буду это делать точно таким же образом, это сработает? Могу ли я использовать, например, файл формата .dat вместо .txt?

Расширение значения не имеет. Запишите все строки в TStringList и сделайте SaveToFile. Или массив строк и System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllLines.

А вон как... Ясно, спасибо! Попробую. А если все-таки попробовать сделать запись в бинарный файл - это сильно сложнее? я не знаю точно, как и куда нужно длину строки записывать в файл, и как отделять длину строки от самой строки...
